# How to backtest small time frame in longer than default?

Tags: pine-script, back-testing

I have a strategy in time frame 5m. I backtest my strategy but I can do only 2 - 3 months. My question is have any way to do the backtest longer than 2 - 3 months for a time frame of 5m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the first bar on the chart and use bar replay on the first bar, you will get another dataset back in time. Can do this a few times.